# How do I resolve the conflict of rules in this .htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Each of the rules in the file works well if I comment out the other, but the two of them together do not achieve either purpose but rather renders the site ugly. Any suggestion on how to resolve this? Thanks.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# do not do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# forward /blog/foo to blog.php/foo
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ blog.php/$1 [L,NC]

# forward /john to user_page/profile.php?name=john
RewriteRule ^((?!blog/).+)$ user_page/profile.php?uid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured this out. I modified the second rewrite condition because the second rewrite rule redirects to a url that is not necessary valid i.e `www.example.com/username` to the intended valid url which looks like this `www.example.com/user_page/profile.php?user=username`.

I also modified the last/second rewrite rule as Safarov suggested and it worked! Below is the full `.htaccess` file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
# OR If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
# OR If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
# do not do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# forward /blog/foo to blog.php/foo
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ blog.php/$1 [L,NC]

# forward /john to user_page/profile.php?name=john
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ user_page/profile.php?uid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: +1 for figuring it all out. However I have made one minor correction in your code and took the liberty to edit your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try replace `RewriteRule ^((?!blog/).+)$` with `RewriteRule ^(.+)$` there is no need to check for `blog` string again

Comment: I've tried that, it maps all the incoming url to user_page/profile.php

Comment: htaccess working flow is up to down, so put all your rules before this. And the rest of will forward to profile.php